# What does it mean when a multi-line comment starts with <<

Tags: ruby, multilinestring

In Ruby, what does it mean when a multi-line comment starts with `<<`?

Comment: This is syntax for multiline strings, not comments. The term is "heredocs"

Answer (score 0):

It defines a way you can enter multiple lines of code that will be ignored by the Ruby interpreter. This multi-line literal feature is called `Here Documents' (shortened to 'heredoc').  Discussed here...

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents

You put your own "keyword" after the `<<` and then use the same keyword after the last line so that Ruby knows where the multi-line assignment stops.

```
x = 1

<<-endofstuff
x = 2
x += 1
endofstuff

p x
=> 1
```

You can see the lines between the << and the keyword are ignored.

However, this is NOT a comment in the usual sense, and does take up some memory allocation.  Chances are good that where you saw the occurence it was, in fact, being used to create a literal that was assigned to a variable or passed to a method.

Using 'heredoc' for commenting isn't recommended and wasn't the original intent of the feature. If used for commenting, it can be confusing to someone reviewing code, especially a long block of code.

Use (instead) the `=begin` and `=end` convention or even better for clarity, an explicit `#` in front of each commented line.

Comment: I'm not sure why you call this multi-line assignment. This is just a multi-line string literal. No assignment is required, for example you could pass it directly as a method argument. Also you're using the `<<-` form which allows white space to appear before the closing keyword.

Comment: This is syntax for strings, not comments.

Comment: Yes, @SergioTulentsev but it can be used for comments and has been referenced as "multi-line comments"  it's a string assignment without a receiving variable.  I'm not saying it's a great technique and it's not something I do, but it answers the OP's question.

Comment: "has been referenced as "multi-line comments" " - well, there's always a possibility that the OP is simply confused and doesn't know it's a string. Also, this literal is not ignored, I think. If you inspect the bytecode, I'm 95% sure it'll be there. Sure, it doesn't do much, but it's not ignored as real comments.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev well it doesn't execute so it's one way to render multiple lines of code 'inert'.  Agreed it's not a true comment, but yes it does take some memory allocation. As an unreferenced object does it get GC'd?  I take your point about OP possibly being confused. If you think the answer just adds to confusion, I'm happy to delete it, let me know.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: I think the answer should stay. I'd add emphasis that this is not a comment. Also, we don't see his original codebase (which prompted the question). I'm willing to bet some money that the heredoc there is, in fact, an active string, with interpolation and stuff. I use them often to generate chunks of html / xml.

Comment: ok @SergioTulentsev thanks for your thoughts, answer modified as you suggested.